How to access PHP-LARAVEL application without development server running?
I am encountering an issue with my microservice deployment. I am using the php:8.0-fpm-alpine image.
During the build process, several dependencies are installed.
I set my working directory to /app using WORKDIR /app and copied the code with the following commands:
COPY composer.json composer.lock ./
COPY . . 
Then, I run composer install, and at the end,
I use
CMD ["php-fpm"]
to start the PHP-FPM process.
I also have an Nginx container where I have defined routes to the PHP container in a configuration file.
Problem:
When I deploy my container and access my application at a URL like:
http://my-domain/myapi/status
I receive a 502 Bad Gateway error. However, if I execute the following commands:
docker exec -it myapi /bin/sh
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80 or 9000

And then access the URL:
http://my-domain/myapi/status
The application works fine.
I do not want to run the Laravel development server inside my container. Instead, my Nginx container should directly serve the application content without relying on the Laravel development server.
Could you please advise on how to resolve this issue?
FROM php:8.0-fpm-alpine
RUN apk update && apk add (dependencies)

WORKDIR /app
COPY composer.json composer.lock ./
COPY . .
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /app/storage /app/bootstrap/cache \
    && chmod -R 775 /app/storage /app/bootstrap/cache
RUN composer install 
CMD ["php-fpm"]

My application should run without using the development server inside the PHP-Laravel container.
My nginx.conf:
upstream php_services {
    server myapi:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
    proxy_send_timeout 60s;
    proxy_read_timeout 60s;

    client_body_timeout 32;
    client_header_timeout 32;
    keepalive_timeout 90;
    send_timeout 300;
    port_in_redirect off;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT, X-CustomHeader, Keep-Alive, User-Agent, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Content-Type' always;

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        return 204;
    }

    location /myapi/ {
        proxy_pass http://myapi:9000/;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/myapi-dir/myapi.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/myapi-dir/myapi.error.log;
        root /home/myapi/public/;
    }

    # ... other APIs ...

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;

        # Use a variable to dynamically set fastcgi_pass
        set $upstream_php php_services;

        fastcgi_pass $upstream_php:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS 200;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 180s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180s;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;

        try_files $uri =404;
    }
}

My Goal:
My ultimate goal is to deploy my image to a Kubernetes cluster, where I can use Nginx as a pod with an ALB (Application Load Balancer) or Nginx Ingress for routing.

You will need to share your nginx configuration because it needs to be configured to serve your PHP application via FPM

When you run your php and nginx containers you'd need to make sure they run on the same network. I think you can achieve this using --network=mynetwork as a flag for both containers then you can use the container id to connect between containers check this though personally I've never used this because I opt for the convenience of using "docker compose"  which simplifies all this

I am using docker-compose and all the microservices are on the same network. @apokryfos

You are using proxy_pass http://myapi:9000/; but that is probably wrong because FPM is a CGI module and not served over HTTP as a proxy. Try to combine the two location directives into one. Also I'm not sure if you're using upstream correctly here. You've defined the port in the upstream configuration and also appending it in the fastcgi_* options. Maybe try to write the most simple configuration for nginx first and get that to work and work your way up
